# Is there a way to tell NPM NOT to use globally installed packages during a build

Tags: node.js, npm

We work in a large team on multiple projects and everyone has a different set of node packages installed globally.

This can cause different behaviour when different members of the team build a project.

Is there a setting in a package.json file (or other file) that we can apply that forces NPM to only use local packages that have been installed in the local project node_modules.

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour?

Comment: I believe I have answered your question. Can you check, upvote and accept it if it meets your requirements, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is more relating to development tools and modules (`netlify`, `standard`, `prettier`, `@babel/core`, `rollup`, `eslint`, etc)

Using `npm i --save-dev package-a package-b package-c` to ensure that you have the exact and correct versions across your development teams. I would suggest looking at `package.json`s in projects like [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/package.json), [react](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/package.json), [nextjs](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/package.json) etc to see how they handle it. It can be quite a task to get a correct baseline of devDependencies, but once set, it generally solves a lot of package dependency problems caused by global modules.

See this: http://npm.github.io/how-npm-works-docs/npm3/how-npm3-works.html